# TeeChart line series plotted points ending with white symbol

Tags: wpf, teechart

I am having a teechart issue as shown in attached [image....](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sDThm.png) , All line series stopped plotting points when any one of the series has null values. Is there any option to over come this issue.. Thanks..

Answer (score 0):

Line and Horiz. Line series can display "null" values in three different ways:

Series1.TreatNulls := tnDontPaint;  // <--- consider null points "empty"

Series1.TreatNulls := tnSkip;  // <--- jump lines to next non-null point

Series1.TreatNulls := tnIgnore;  // <--- consider null points as "zero" or any other "Y" value.